# JSON.Net filtering escape strings before using DeserializeObject, Best Practices

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am using JSON.Net and the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function to load the json into objects.
Often the json uses escape strings that causes the DeserializeObject to fail.
Some of the escapes are:

> \' \u0027 allow to enter a ' in a character literal, e.g. '\''
>
> \" \u0022 allow to enter a " in a string literal, e.g. "this is the double quote (\") character"
>
> \ \u005c allow to enter a \ character in a character or string literal, e.g. '\' or "this is the backslash (\) character"
>
> \0 \u0000 allow to enter the character with code 0
>
> \a \u0007 alarm (usually the HW beep)
>
> \b \u0008 back-space
>
> \f \u000c form-feed (next page)
>
> \n \u000a line-feed (next line)
>
> \r \u000d carriage-return (move to the beginning of the line)
>
> \t \u0009 (horizontal-) tab
>
> \v \u000b vertical-tab

There is an article and code at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma
some escape codes such as /r /n probably are not needed because C# will understand them.

Is there a best practice into escaping these escape codes in json files?
I want to create a full class to handle the data before passing it to the DeserializeObject.

Any ideas from anyone? Easy points for someone who understands json.net and regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert the json escapes sequences back in to C# escape sequences.

If so, you should be able to simply search for json escapes and replace them with the actual C# escape:

```
var test = value.Replace(@"\u0085","\u0085");
```

I guess in theory, you could reverse Json.Net's utility function `ToEscapedJavaScriptString()` to go from json escapes to C# escapes.

The following code is a slightly modded version of Json.Net's string serialization I wrote using their code found [on codeplex](http://json.codeplex.com/). I combined it in to one helper class. This is how they convert a string from C# to json, so maybe it will help.

```
// Copyright (c) 2007 James Newton-King    
namespace Demo
    {
        using System.Globalization;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Text;

        public class JsonHelper
        {
            public static string ToJson(string value, char delimiter = '"', bool appendDelimiters = true)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    return value;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    WriteEscapedString(sw, value, delimiter, appendDelimiters);
                    return sw.ToString();
                }
            }

            private static void WriteEscapedString(TextWriter writer, string s, char delimiter, bool appendDelimiters)
            {
                // leading delimiter
                if (appendDelimiters)
                    writer.Write(delimiter);

                if (s != null)
                {
                    char[] chars = null;
                    int lastWritePosition = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = s[i];

                        // don't escape standard text/numbers except '\' and the text delimiter
                        if (c >= ' ' && c < 128 && c != '\\' && c != delimiter)
                            continue;

                        string escapedValue;

                        switch (c)
                        {
                            case '\t': escapedValue = @"\t"; break;
                            case '\n': escapedValue = @"\n"; break;
                            case '\r': escapedValue = @"\r"; break;
                            case '\f': escapedValue = @"\f"; break;
                            case '\b': escapedValue = @"\b"; break;
                            case '\\': escapedValue = @"\\"; break;
                            case '\u0085': escapedValue = @"\u0085"; break; // Next Line
                            case '\u2028': escapedValue = @"\u2028"; break; // Line Separator
                            case '\u2029': escapedValue = @"\u2029"; break; // Paragraph Separator
                            case '\'': escapedValue = @"\'"; break;
                            case '"': escapedValue = "\\\""; break;
                            default: escapedValue = (c <= '\u001f') ? ToUnicode(c) : null; break;
                        }

                        if (escapedValue == null)
                            continue;

                        if (i > lastWritePosition)
                        {
                            if (chars == null)
                                chars = s.ToCharArray();

                            // write unchanged chars before writing escaped text
                            writer.Write(chars, lastWritePosition, i - lastWritePosition);
                        }

                        lastWritePosition = i + 1;
                        writer.Write(escapedValue);
                    }

                    if (lastWritePosition == 0)
                        // no escaped text, write entire string
                        writer.Write(s);
                    else
                    {
                        if (chars == null)
                            chars = s.ToCharArray();

                        // write remaining text
                        writer.Write(chars, lastWritePosition, s.Length - lastWritePosition);
                    }
                }

                // trailing delimiter
                if (appendDelimiters)
                    writer.Write(delimiter);
            }

            private static string ToUnicode(char c)
            {
                char h1 = ToHex((c >> 12) & '\x000f');
                char h2 = ToHex((c >> 8) & '\x000f');
                char h3 = ToHex((c >> 4) & '\x000f');
                char h4 = ToHex(c & '\x000f');

                return new string(new[] { '\\', 'u', h1, h2, h3, h4 });
            }

            private static char ToHex(int n)
            {
                if (n <= 9)
                    return (char)(n + 48);
                return 
                    (char)((n - 10) + 97);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a giant blob of code you got there! Would it be possible to just post the core part that is related to the question?